# Send commands from client to server in C# without using WCF

Tags: client

I would like to send commands to a server from a client application without have to create my own protocol or message structure.  I am mainly wondering what options I have besides WCF.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the calls, you could just use HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 1):

you could use TCPClient and TCPListener

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx